# Org Src Block does not return any output

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, shell

TL;DR: How do I get the stderr of my source block to be part of the #+RESULTS block, without changing the contents of the block? I can only get stdout to appear.

---

[Long and winding explanation]

While writing this question I found a solution/reason to it not working.
Since I spent quite some time on it, I thought I'd still post it.

Hey there!

I'm relatively new to emacs and org mode especially. Last month, I started writing my bachelor's thesis for applied computer science using org mode (based on [dangom's](https://github.com/dangom/org-thesis) template).

In the thesis, I use `org-src` blocks to demonstrate stuff.
In this case, I've set up an example to demonstrate warnings from a `C` Compiler:

```
#+CAPTION: A simple C-Program without errors, but with a Code Smell
#+NAME: qc:c-code
#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [H]
#+BEGIN_SRC C :tangle ../sourcecodes/foo.c
// foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i=10;
}
#+END_SRC
```

As you can see, this *program* is stored in a seperate `sourcecodes` folder:

```
├── backmatter
├── frontmatter
├── images
├── library.bib
├── literatur
├── mainmatter
│   └── 03-analysis.org <- This is where I am
├── sourcecodes
│   ├── foo
│   └── foo.c <- and here goes the program
└── thesis
```

Now, I wish to build that file.

```
#+CAPTION: ...
#+NAME: qc:c-code-build
#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [H]
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output :dir ../sourcecodes
gcc foo.c -Wall -o foo
#+END_SRC
```

In this example, I use the `dir` header to change the directory for execution of the code.

When run in a terminal, this results to this:

```
foo.c: In function 'main':
foo.c:5:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
    5 |     int i=10;
      |         ^
```

This is what I would expect.
In emacs, it results to this:

```
#+RESULTS: qc:c-code-build
```

Whereas this

```
#+CAPTION: ...
#+NAME: qc:c-code-build
#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [H]
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output :dir ../sourcecodes
ls
gcc --version
gcc foo.c -Wall -o foo
ls
#+END_SRC
```

returns that:

```
#+RESULTS: qc:c-code-build
: foo.c
: gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
: Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
: This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
: warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
: 
: foo
: foo.c
```

Now, obviously this is not a real problem - just copy and paste the desired output into a `src` block your own.

I would just like to know if I'm missing something super obvious.

Other stuff I've tried/noticed:

- Using `shell` instead of `sh`
- `results: output replace`
- `:exports both`
- created a minimal example, which does not load anything from the template
- tried to use scimax  (and failed, since by default it doesn't contain the org-babel-execute function for sh/shell)
- some Buffer once gave me errors (`Error Output` or something)

Now, as promised, the reason:

[Org-mode shell source blocks do not capture stderr](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/04/Redirecting-stderr-in-org-mode-shell-blocks)

My solution for the problem:
I don't have a good solution for this as of yet. The solution of John Kitchin suggests use of `2>&1` which writes all stderr to stdout, for example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output replace :dir ../sourcecodes :exports both
gcc foo.c -Wall -o foo 2>&1
#+END_SRC
```

But that adds some unnecessary logic to the eye for the reader of the thesis, which is why I'm probably staying with copy-pasting stderr into src-blocks (except someone has a better solution)

Comment: What's the question? A quick reading gives me the impression that you're providing an answer to your question as part of the question. If so, please don't do that. Pose a straightforward question, if you have one. You can also then pose a straightforward answer to it, if you like. As it stands now, it doesn't seem like you have a real question.

Comment: I guess the question is roughly: "how to obtain stderr output without changing the source block content".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rephrasing and shortening, I guess the question is roughly: "how to obtain stderr output without changing the source block content?"

By skimming the comments section of the [John Kitchin's post](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/04/Redirecting-stderr-in-org-mode-shell-blocks/), adding

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sh :prologue "exec 2>&1" :epilogue ":"
```

globally, at the top of the file, should do the job (it works in my side).

Comment: I *knew* this was going to be useful: I upvoted it before, but I just needed it again today and I would upvote it again if I could :-)